# how to find class of anchor from span within anchor

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have the following html code. When I click on the span and run the javascript function, I would like to find the class of the anchor tag that the span is nested within.  In the code below, when I click on the span, I need the javascript to determine "button".

```
<a class="button"><span id="test1" onclick="doFunction(this)">some text</span></a>
```

Comment: Have you tried *anything at all*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a `doFunction` that looks like this:

```
function doFunction(elem) {
   /* code */
}
```

You can get the parent element's class with `elem.parentElement.className`

Comment: I think you mean `parentNode`. *edit:* Uh `parentElement` exists as well: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.parentElement . All those new fancy DOM APIs :P

Comment: Excellent!  I used the code below.
`function doFunction(here) {
var myId = here.id;
var yaya = document.getElementById(myId).parentElement.className;`

Comment: You should be able to simplify that to `var yaya = here.parentElement.className;` unless I've misunderstood something.

Answer (score 0):

If jQuery is okay:

```
<a class="button"><span id="test1">some text</span></a>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function () {
    $(document).on("click", "#test1", function () {
        console.log($(this).parent().attr('class'));
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: From the [tag:javascript] tag description: *"Unless a tag for a framework/library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected."*